# How to store the mouse click events in xlib programming

Tags: c, xlib, x11

I am using xlib draw a figure and give some events as input to draw certain on the window.I want to know how can i save these events results? Because on window resize all my results disappears.

How can i save the results of each event so that on resize(where it calls the expose event) the results of previous events remains on the screen.

Comment: I believe you're looking for information on [gravity attributes](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/attributes/gravity.html), but I'm an Xlib newb as well and haven't looked into it.

Comment: yes!!looks like its something related to gravity attr, I am also a newb in xlib , i dont have much idea on how to implement it.Any help from someone is highly appreciated.

Comment: you still need to be able to repeat all drawing commands even if your gravity setting does not discard window content on resize. Map/unmap could throw away all your modifications. You are expected to restore window content in response to Expose notification.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember xlib if you loose content of the window when resizing it means you didn't register your callback for refresh event. Copy your drawing code into this callback and everything should be ok.